# How to export a bulk of csv from Xcode simulator to mac?

Tags: swift, xcode, csv, export, ios-simulator

In Xcode using simulator I create and save certain amount of csv files into path:

```
let path = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                               in: .allDomainsMask,
                                               appropriateFor: nil,
                                               create: false)
```

and I want to export them as a package (around 1gb big) to `/Users/User/Documents/` on my Mac.

How to extract them from the simulator app?

Comment: Do you need this to be done programatically (that's not possible directly from Swift code, since the Simulator is running in sandbox mode and hence has no access to the rest of the file system)? Or is it fine if you have to copy the files manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Documents directory will be stored in the path (at least Xcode 11+):

`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{Device Identifier (GUID)}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{App Identifier (GUID)}/Documents`

You should find the CSV files in that folder. You can find the Device Identifier by navigating to `Window->Devices and Simulators`, then click on `Simulators` segment control and select the current simulator device on the left. The right panel should then show the simulator details, copy the value in `Identifier:` field.

A quick way to find the App ID (and the path to all CSVs) is to run the following command in the Terminal, however, this will show all apps on that particular simulator with files of filetype `.csv`:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{Device GUID}/data/Containers/Data/Application && find . -name '*.csv'
```

This will return something like:

```
./{App GUID}/Documents/{Filename}.csv
```